# how to find all outer tag,not contained child tag

Tags: jquery

i want find all the outer tag ,and set each id in order like

```
<p><span/></p>
<table>
   <tr>
       <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

i want to like

```
 <p id = "1"><span/></p>
    <table id = "2">
       <tr>
           <td></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```

but when i use find("*"),will find `p ,span,table,tr,td`,

my js is

```
$("body").find("*").each(function (index) {
       $(this).attr("id",index);
   });
```

the result is

```
<p id = "1"><span id = "2"/></p>
    <table id = "3">
       <tr id = "4">
           <td id = "5"></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```

how to solve it?

Comment: Outer tags of which element?How we can determine that element(By tag name or by mabye a class name or by Id)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to target only the children of the body element, not all descendants so use [.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

```js
$("body").children().attr('id', function(idx) {
  return idx
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span>1</span></p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you want to use only find not children then

```js
$("body").find(' > *').attr('id', function(idx) {
  return idx
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span>1</span></p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks very much,but i want find the p and table tag which is the outer tag with find method,not the child tag